# Проектирование локальной сети

Tags: сеть, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

Здание звучит так спроектировать локальную сеть из 15 компьютеров и 1 преподавательского, При том что преподавательский должен видеть в сети все Пк , а остальные Пк его не видели . Работаю в программа Cisco Packet Tracer , Сеть построил все сделал , не пойму как сделать чтоб его не видели а он видел ) прошу помощи.

Answer (score 2):

А что значит видели ?  Не могли установить с ним соединение например по TCP?!

Если так то вам надо закрыть tcp syn  со стороны полльзовательских компов.

Делается это с помощью cisco [ACL](http://xgu.ru/wiki/Cisco_ACL) на управляемых коммутаторах.

Comment: может имеется ввиду что преподский за nat поместить ?

Comment: А я вообще не вижу смысла в подобном извращении (сокрытие преподского из списка сети - как я понял, именно это имеется в виду в задании). Закрыть от доступа на него (локальный файерволл на преподской машине) - это можно понять.

Comment: Спасибо за дельный совет , а можно по подробнее как это все правильнее сделать , например компьютера пользователей можно же поставить диапазоном ? чтобы они не видели Преподаватели и какие команды лучше для этого подойдут . сам новичок в этом деле вот хочу разобраться

Comment: А почему бы не сделать это сресдствами ОС. Если ось семейства Win7 и выше, просто в параметрах общего доступа вырубаем сетевое обнаружение, если другие оси, тогда уточните какая ось на ПК преподавателя, и хотелось бы подробнее расшифровку фразы "не видели".

Comment: @Truebosher1 - настраиваем доступы к преподавательскому компу:  1) т.е. доступы к расшаренным папкам (если таковые нужны) строго ограничить (убрать "все", вставить нужных пользователей);  2) в файерволле разрешить ПО удаленного управления (должен же препод управлять или наблюдать за машинами сети - если такая задача стоит) - все остальное запретить.  ну и т.п.